# Ballerina SQL Parameterized Queries

Tags: sql, database, prepared-statement, ballerina

I have the following function which retrieves a user from a SQL database.

```all
isolated function getUser(string userId) returns UserData|error {
    io:println("[User ID]: ", userId);
    sql:ParameterizedQuery query = `SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = "${userId}"`;
    io:println("[Query]: ", query);
    return dbClient->queryRow(query);
}
```

When invoked, this function prints the following:

```
[User ID]: 91c7571c-5524-4f88-9e75-743fb94c3b48
[Query]: SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = "91c7571c-5524-4f88-9e75-743fb94c3b48"
```

But after the execution, it throws the following error:

```
Error while executing SQL query: SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = \" ? \". Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `"` around the parameter causes the issue. I was able to resolve it after removing the quotes around the `id` parameter.

The following line:

```all
sql:ParameterizedQuery query = `SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = "${userId}"`;
```

Should be changed to:

```all
sql:ParameterizedQuery query = `SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ${userId}`;
```